# MySQL Enterprise backup (mysqlbackup). Log progress into file but don't report it to stderr

Tags: mysql, backup

When using MySQL Enterprise Backup I am interested in keeping a record of the progress in the `MEB-`*<timestamp>*`-`*<operation>*`.log` file, as usual, but I don't want to get the same output via stderr. (If possible to reserve stderr to actual warnings and errors)

Is there a way to accomplish this?